# How do you select a file using drag and drop in Java paintComponent?

Tags: java, drag-and-drop

I am working on a text file encryption project. I have used paint component to make a simple GUI, but I want the user to be able to drag a text file into a specified rectangle and have it select the text file. I have looked at videos and at other stack overflow posts, but they all tell you how to drag and drop into a JTextField or other swing component.

This is what the screen looks like when you open the program.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GraphicsClass extends JPanel {

int screen = 0;
int buttonColor = 0;
int error = 0;
boolean selected = false;

public GraphicsClass() {

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());                  // Background
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(0, 60, getWidth(), 10);                          // Tab Line
    if(screen==0) {
        g.fillRect(50, 10, 200, 50);                            // Active Encrypt Tab
    }
    else if(screen==1) {
        g.fillRect(270, 10, 200, 50);                           // Active Decrypt Tab
    }
    g.fillRect(10, 100, getWidth()-20, 600);                    // Green Drag File Here Corners
    g.setColor(new Color(0,120,0));
    if(screen==1) {
        g.fillRect(50, 10, 200, 50);                            // Inactive Encrypt Tab
    }
    else if(screen==0) {
        g.fillRect(270, 10, 200, 50);                           // Inactive Decrypt Tab
    }
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 24));
    if(screen==0) {
        g.fillRect(60, 20, 180, 50);                            // Active Center Encrypt Tab
        g.fillRect(280, 20, 180, 40);                           // Inactive Center Decrypt Tab
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawString("Encrypt", 103, 47);
        g.setColor(new Color(0,120,0));
        g.drawString("Decrypt", 323, 47);
    }
    else if(screen==1) {
        g.fillRect(60, 20, 180, 40);                            // Inactive Center Decrypt Tab
        g.fillRect(280, 20, 180, 50);                           // Active Center Decrypt Tab
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawString("Decrypt", 323, 47);
        g.setColor(new Color(0,120,0));
        g.drawString("Encrypt", 103, 47);
    }
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(20, 110, getWidth()-40, 580);                    // Black Center Rectangle 
    g.fillRect(100, 90, getWidth()-200, getHeight());           // Vertical Black Cross
    g.fillRect(0, 200, getWidth(), 400);                        // Horizontal Black Cross
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 48));
    g.drawString("Drag a file here", 275, 320);
    g.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 36));
    g.drawString("-- OR --", 410, 475);
    if(buttonColor==1 || selected==false) {
        g.setColor(new Color(0,120,0));
    }
    g.fillRect(10, getHeight()-115, getWidth()-20, 105);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    if(buttonColor==2) {
        g.setColor(new Color(0,120,0));
    }
    g.fillRect(325, 600, 350, 100);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(16, getHeight()-109, getWidth()-32, 93);
    g.fillRect(331, 606, 338, 88);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 48));
    if(buttonColor==1 || selected==false) {
        g.setColor(new Color(0,120,0));
    }
    if(screen==0) {
        g.drawString("Encrypt", 395, getHeight()-50);
    }
    else if(screen==1) {
        g.drawString("Decrypt", 395, getHeight()-50);
    }
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    if(buttonColor==2) {
        g.setColor(new Color(0,120,0));
    }
    g.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 36));
    g.drawString("Select a file", 355, 660);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    if(error==1) {
        g.drawString("ERROR: Empty file", 310, getHeight()-180);
    }
    else if(error==2) {
        g.drawString("ERROR: File not encrypted", 220, getHeight()-180);
    }
    else if(error==3) {
        g.drawString("ERROR: File already encrypted", 180, getHeight()-180);
    }
    else if(error==4) {
        g.drawString("ERROR: Not a .txt file", 255, getHeight()-180);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I am not a Java programmer, but that is a lot of code. Is it all necessary for the question? If not, I would advise removing the unnecessary items, so that it is easier to read.

Comment: I think this is worth to read first. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html

Comment: @Nguyen Doan Tung I have read before that but it all appeared to be about dragging and dropping into GUI components not paintComponent